# Interior and closure of a set with metric you can't visualize

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$X = \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1 \right\}$

$d((x,y), (x',y')) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    1 & , y \neq y'\\
    |x - x'| & , y = y'
  \end{array}
\right.$

> Find the interior and closure of $\left\{ (\frac{1}{n}, y) : 0 \leq y \leq 1, n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$ and $\left\{ (x, \frac{1}{n}) : 0 \leq x \leq 1, n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$.

I can't visualize this metric so I'm not sure how it behaves, thus I can't visualize the interior and closure like I would be able to if this were a Euclidean metric. In cases like these where you can't geometrically analyze the interior and closure, what options are there to solve this by purely analytical or algebraic measures when you have no intuition of what's going on?

For the first set, I would guess that every point $(x,y)$ is isolated, so the interior is every point of the set. Since every point is isolated, the set has no limit points so it seems it is closed, but towards the $y-$axis, it looks like it might be open if we don't include the $y-$axis. So that means the set is not closed, even though it has no limit points? How is this possible?

Comment: Can you find out how a "ball" with small radius looks in that metric? Fix $(x_0,y_0)\in X$ and an $\varepsilon < 1$, and try to determine the set $$B_{\varepsilon}(x_0,y_0) = \{ (x,y)\in X : d((x_0,y_0),(x,y)) < \varepsilon\}.$$ If you can do that, you will start to see how interior and closure of subsets of $X$ look like.

Comment: One observation that may help is that all the horizontal segments are open sets. This shows that a horizontal segment is both open and closed in this topology.

Comment: One more comment: points at different heights are isolated from each other. So for fixed $n$, $\{(\frac{1}{n},y): 0\leq y \leq 1\}$ is a bunch of disjoint points. Its closure for fixed $n$ must then be itself (the only convergent sequences are the constant ones).